# How to check if a domain name is a CNAME in PHP

Tags: php, url, dns, cname

How do I check if the URL accessing the page is the original URL or if it's a CNAME record.

For example, I have a site `domain.com`. Users can setup a CNAME where they link `www.otherdomain.com` to our site `domain.com`.

From our server point of view, how can I detect if the URL accessing the page is the actual one (`domain.com`) or the CNAME one (`www.otherdomain.com`)?

Comment: Does this sort of think require a dedicated IP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have to query a DNS to know it, since this information does not usually come in request headers.

Take a look at the [dns_get_record](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php) and [checkdnsrr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) functions in PHP documentation.

Comment: dns_get_record is the correct answer. I got it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PHPDNS](http://www.purplepixie.org/phpdns/usage_guide.php) class library to find out what kind of DNS record is a given url.

```
$answer->results[x]->typeid //Textual record type ID (A, MX, CNAME etc)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're checking on URLs, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in PHP. That's the requested host from the URL (eg. http://otherdomain.com/blah.php would make the server var be `otherdomain.com`). `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is the configured servername in the httpd.conf.

If HTTP_HOST != SERVER_NAME, the remote user is almost certainly using an alias of some sort to access the site.

Comment: Both HTTP_HOST and HTTP_NAME are giving me otherdomain.com