# CNAME Domain Forwarding Support

Tags: php, subdomain, cname

Lets say for example my website address is: www.example.com

I let my users each have a website at user1.example.com, user2.example.com - I have achieved this through wildcard sub domains etc.

How can I let my users have these sites (which I host) at specialpage.theirsite.com? They would add a cname record for specialpage pointing to userpages.example.com - How would I handle hosting these pages once they have been pointed? *Preferably in PHP!*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a domain name is a CNAME in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232661/how-to-check-if-a-domain-name-is-a-cname-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use [CloudFlare wildcard DNS entries](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168826-Does-CloudFlare-support-wildcard-DNS-entries-) to point all unset subdomains to the A record for userpages.example.com and then use a php script in the directory for userpages.example.com to check if the subdomain has been setup.

```
<?php
$subdomain = array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
if ($subdomain IN DATABASE) echo DATABASEOUTPUT;
else echo 'Domain: "' . $subdomain . '.example.com"';
?>
```